# Why is (Z/2Z)* cyclic?

Tags: group-theory

I see it claimed that (Z/2Z)* is a cyclic group, but it doesn't seem to me that it has a generator. It is the set {0,1}, both elements of which are their own square. So it seems to me that each element has order 1 and the group is not cyclic. Why is this a cyclic group?

Comment: The set is $\{1\}$, not $\{0, 1\}$.

Comment: Read the definition of your group again. The asterisk in $(\Bbb{Z}/n\Bbb{Z})^*$ means that only those cosets $a+n\Bbb{Z}$ are included where $\gcd(a,n)=1$. In your case $\gcd(0,2)=2$, so $0+2\Bbb{Z}$ is not an element. The trivial group is trivially cyclic

Comment: Thanks! We only just started going over cosets. So the multiplicative group of integers mod z never includes 0?

Answer (score 0):

The multiplicative group of a group $G$ is the collection of all those elements of the group which have a **multiplicative** inverse. In your case $\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}$ does $\bar{0}$ have an element $\bar{a} \in \Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}$ such that $\bar{0a} = 1$ ?

Note that this is true for $\Bbb{Z}/n\Bbb{Z}$ for any $n$. In general you define the multiplicative group of $G$ (or the group of units, as its sometimes called) on $G-\{0\}$